# How do I populate a <p> tag with text in Selenium Webdriver using PhantomJS?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, webautomation

I have an input form that I need to populate with text. It's a div and it has a child node that is a

tag that needs to be populated with text in order to submit the form.

I've tried send_keys on the div itself to no avail, and in my browser I selected the

tag and changed it's TextContent property which resulted in the message box being filled with the text, so I know the

tag has to be filled, but using send_keys on it does not work:

```
textbox = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@role='textbox']/p[1]")[0]
print(textbox)
//<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a0712590-511d-11e6-8e12-dbe0d5eb709e", element=":wdc:1469309865349")>
```

**Now with send_keys:**

```
   textbox = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@role='textbox']/p[1]")[0]
   textbox.send_keys("This is a test")
//selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error Message => 
''undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a.value.length')'
```

My question is, how can I enter text input into this text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send_keys()` works only on that element which needs to be set value on their `value` attribute means `input` and `textarea`, but here you are trying to set value on `p` element which need to be set on their `textContent`, So here you should try using `execute_script()` as below :-

```
textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@role='textbox']/p[1]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent = arguments[1];", textbox, "This is a test")
```

Or

```
textbox = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@role='textbox']/p[1]")[0]
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent = arguments[1];", textbox, "This is a test")
```

Hope it helps...:)